# Progress Bar com AsyncTask e com vários links de download

Tags: android, asynctask

Tenho uma AsyncTask que faz download de várias imagens que passo por um ArrayList com os links para download e utilizo um progress bar e não está funcionando perfeitamente.

A barra de progresso reinicia a cada link que faz o download da imagem, penso que tenho que somar tamanho de cada imagem dos links e depois começar a fazer o progress bar a rodar, para fazer teste tenho um ArrayList com 9 links o progress bar reinicia 9 vezes.

qual seria e melhor forma de implementar um progress bar com vários download?

```
class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Integer, String> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Download em progresso...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params) {

        ArrayList<String> path = params[0];
        int count = 0;

        for (String urlImage : path) {
            int file_length = 0;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlImage);
                URLConnection urlconnection = url.openConnection();
                urlconnection.connect(); // ok
                file_length = urlconnection.getContentLength();

                String fileName = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(url)).getLastPathSegment();

                File imput_file = new File(new_folder, fileName);

                InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                int total = 0;

                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imput_file);

                while ((count = inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    outputStream.write(data, 0, count);
                    int progress = (int) total * 100 / file_length;
                    publishProgress(progress);
                }
                inputStream.close();
                outputStream.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "Download finalizado!";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressDialog.hide();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

valeu.

Comment: Reverti a sua edição, que acrescenta [Fechada] ao título, porque essa indicação é feita ao ter aceite uma resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que funcione, `file_length`, em `int progress = (int) total * 100 / file_length` teria de ser a soma dos comprimentos de todas as imagens.
Isso obrigaria a que, antes de ler as imagens, ter de criar e abrir uma *connection* e utilizar `urlconnection.getContentLength()` para cada uma delas, o que não seria muito eficiente.

Uma abordagem possível é fazer evoluir o *ProgressBar* cada vez que uma imagem é baixada:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params) {

    ArrayList<String> path = params[0];
    int count = 0;
    int imagesCount = path.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < imagesCount; i++){

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlImage.get(i));

            String fileName = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(url)).getLastPathSegment();

            File imput_file = new File(new_folder, fileName);

            InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int total = 0;

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imput_file);

            while ((count = inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                outputStream.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();

            int progress = i * 100 / imagesCount;
            publishProgress(progress);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return "Download finalizado!";
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu precisava...valeu mesmo!